# Can I use Google Analytics to track a specific referrer URL?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, goal-tracking

I have a *Featured Product* block on my website's home page. I'd like to track it's efficacy by adding a handle `?referrer=featured` to it and then have Google Analytics track checkout on said product.

I'm assuming I'd need to set up a goal to do so, I looked at the options via `Admin` → `Goals` → `New Goal` but can't seem to find anything relevant there.

Will I need to put a specific tracking code in the template page for the product? The tricky bit is that the featured product is changed daily, so I'd like to track if **anybody** buys **any** featured product by clicking on the block, hence why I was thinking of the URL handle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just set it up as [an event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) and then track the event. It will appear in the Events section of your Google Analytics profile and you can also set up [a goal based on that event](http://analytics.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/new-google-analytics-events-goals.html).

You can create the event [here](http://gaconfig.com/google-analytics-event-tracking/).

[image: Google Analytics Event Tracking]

Comment: thanks. Is there some manner in which to track if this event results in a conversion (i.e checking out)?

Comment: Set up a goal in GA for conversions/sales (which I'd assume you already have set up) and then you'd be able to load up the event in GA and view goal completions within the event thus giving you the information you want.

Comment: Nice answer! Very precise.